# How can I select with jQuery and use javascript method to apply a change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use a variation of this code, but I'm having a bit of trouble concatenating the following snippet. Essentially using a for loop from a returned value.length and append the buttons, then replace data for buttons:

```
for(var i...){
var button = "'<button>%data%</button>'";
$(".buttons").append(button).replace("%data%", var); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the replace after you append the element. You should just set `var` directly on element either with `text` or `html`, depending on what `var` holds. Also, please notice that jQuery doesn't have a method called `replace`, it only has `replaceWith` (http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) and  `replaceAll` (http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/).

```
for(var i...){
    var button = $("<button></button>").text(var);
    $(".buttons").append(button); 
};
```